# Still Need Help! The best overloaded method match for 'XDevkit.IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(uint, uint, byte[], out uint)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, byte, syntax-error, object-reference, invalid-argument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The best overloaded method match for 'XDevkit.IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(uint, uint, byte[], out uint)' has some invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145636/the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-xdevkit-ixboxdebugtarget-getmemoryuint-u)

Not sure why this is being voted down, I just need help. I have been struggling with this for hours and I am about done, please if you don't like the post just move on don't vote this down so no one can see it!

Ok I have googled and read through answers and questions like this forever, but have not found an explanation that I can understand for either of these problems I am having, I hope someone on here can help!

Error1: The best overloaded method match for 'XDevkit.IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(uint, uint, byte[], out uint)' has some invalid arguments

The Base Code:

```
XDevkit.IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(uint, uint, byte[], out uint)
```

What I have **NEW**:

```
        uint num1;
        uint num2;
        uint num4;


        num1 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox2.Text);
        num2 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox3.Text);
        num4 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox5.Text);
        byte[] num3;
        num3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));


        IXboxManager xbm = new XboxManager();
        IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole("textBox1.Text"); //Or Console Name in "" 
        IXboxDebugTarget xdt = xbc.DebugTarget;
        xdt.ConnectAsDebugger("XeDevMemPatcher", XboxDebugConnectFlags.Force); // this isn't always needed 
        IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(num1, num2, num3[], out num4);

    }
```

**EDIT Current Errors With This Code**

1) The name 'Encoding' does not exist in the current context

2) The best overloaded method match for   'XDevkit.IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(uint, uint,    byte[], out uint)' has some invalid     2222arguments

3) Argument 3: cannot convert from 'byte' to 'byte[]'

Ok, so this is apparently exceptionally confusing as nothing I do alone or based on answers works, so I am just going to post the entire source on here for you guys to view and hopefully that will help:
Sorry I cannot post a picture of the GUI because I do not have enough REP, but hopefully this should be fine:

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XDevkit
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IXboxManager xbm = new XboxManager();
        //IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole(xbm.DefaultConsole); // dev 
        IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole("textBox1.Text");
        IXboxDebugTarget xdt = xbc.DebugTarget;
        xdt.ConnectAsDebugger("XeDevMemPatcher", XboxDebugConnectFlags.Force);

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    uint num1 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox2.Text);
    uint num2 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox3.Text);
    byte[] num3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox4.Text);
    uint num4 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox5.Text);
    int num5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);

// ...

    if (num3.Length > 1) 
    {    
        IXboxManager xbm = new XboxManager();
        IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole("textBox1.Text");
        IXboxDebugTarget xdt = xbc.DebugTarget;
        xdt.ConnectAsDebugger("XeDevMemPatcher", XboxDebugConnectFlags.Force);
        IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(num1, num2, num3[1], out num4);
}

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a;
        a = "textBox6.Text";

        IXboxManager xbm = new XboxManager();
        IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole(textBox1.Text);
        IXboxConsole.ScreenShot(a)

    }
}
```

}

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `num3` is a byte, so what would `num3[1]` even mean? What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: I know that, but if you look at the base code it calls for a byte and indexer

Comment: Ah, I see. It actually calls for an array of bytes, whereas you are passing a single byte. Are you sure you're calling this method correctly? For example, you are assigning a value to `num4`, but `num4` is an `out` parameter, which is guaranteed to be overwritten by the method.

Comment: No I am not sure it is being called correctly, I switched to using Dennis Traub's solution for calling them, but yes num4 is supposed to be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1:** `num3` is of type `byte`, which doesn't have an indexer.

The example might work if you modified the code to the following:

```
    uint num1 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox2.Text);
    uint num2 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox3.Text);
    byte[] num3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox4.Text);
    uint num4 = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox5.Text);
    int num5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);

    // ...

    if (num3.Length > 1) {    
        IXboxManager xbm = new XboxManager();
        IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole("textBox1.Text");
        IXboxDebugTarget xdt = xbc.DebugTarget;
        xdt.ConnectAsDebugger("XeDevMemPatcher", XboxDebugConnectFlags.Force);
        IXboxDebugTarget.GetMemory(num1, num2, num3[1], out num4);
    }
```

**Error 2:** `IXboxConsole.ScreenShot` is an instance method and not a class (aka static) method. You have to create an instance before you can call instance methods:

```
IXboxManager xbm = new XboxManager();
IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole(textBox1.Text);
xbc.ScreenShot("screenshot");
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that much out, but what do I do instead as the base code calls for an indexer, and won't work without one

Comment: Without knowing the base code or what you're trying to do, the way to fix the issue is to declare num3 to be of type `byte[]` instead of `byte`.

Comment: @user, the base code does not call for an "indexer".  It calls for an *array*.

Comment: @CodeHxr I told you the base code in the post for both strings

Comment: @KirkWoll What does that mean?

Comment: @user, a byte array:  `var byteArray = new byte[5];`  An indexer:  `byteArray[1]`.  They are completely different concepts, and the method consumes the former, not the latter.

Comment: @Dennis Traub

That code gives me the error:

Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'XDevkit.IXboxConsole

Comment: Then you probably need a concrete implementation. Especially if `IXboxConsole` is an interface, you won't be able to directly invoke methods in it.

Comment: @user1205336 That makes sense: in C#, if a type is named ISomething, it almost always indicates an interface (which cannot be instantiated on its own.) In general, you need to create a new object which *implements* the interface, and then call the method on that object.

Comment: @DennisTraub 

IXBOXCONSOLE is an interface, what would this require me to do?

Comment: How do I create an instance for the IxboxConsole interface?

Comment: @user1205336 it would probably help to read a book or two on object-oriented programming. Nevertheless, I updated my answer.

Comment: Here is what I have now:

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a;
            a = "textBox6.Text";

            IXboxManager xbm = new XboxManager();
            IXboxConsole xbc = xbm.OpenConsole(textBox1.Text);
            IXboxConsole.ScreenShot(a)

But it is giving me the error: Error 4 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'XDevkit.IXboxConsole.ScreenShot(string)' 

But I thought I already referenced an object? Also, where could I find some good info on object-oriented programming?

Comment: As I said, `IXboxConsole.ScreenShot(a)` won't work. You must call the method on an actual object. Which you already have, it's `xbc`. Try `xbc.Screenshot(a)`. (I had an error in my answer, sorry if I confused you there, corrected it)

Comment: I LOVE YOU! fixed the screenshot error, I did not read that part of your comment, thank you so much for that, also I posted my source so maybe that will help a bit with the byte array deal

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear from the error message.  `num3` is not a byte array so you cannot access it with an array index.  You will need to convert whatever `textbox3.Text` is to a byte array if you want to access it like you want.  You haven't provided us with this information.

Edit:

If you want to convert the value in the textbox to a byte array, you can do the following:

```
byte[] num3 = BitConvert.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
```

Then you can access `num3[1]` as desired (providing the array is at least a length of 1).

Comment: What information specifically do you need?

Comment: Whatever value you have in `textBox3.Text` needs to be a *byte array*, not a *byte*.

Comment: @ Bryan Crosby

How would I go about converting the text into a byte Array?

Comment: @user1205336: You can use the above edit to convert to a byte array.

Comment: I tried that, for some reason it is still giving me errors, this is a real pain :/

Comment: @user1205336: Your problems are now out of scope of the question.  Please create a new question.